# Sometime there is an extra spacing(margin) in Xcode 8 (auto layout), why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I put a view and set its trailing to superview with 0 spacing, but there is an extra spacing. I Don't know why this occurs, I clear constraints and add new constraints but space remains. Is there a bug, or I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the the `Constraint to margins`. Layout margins represent padding around the interior of a UIView that the layout system can use when laying out subviews - to ensure that a gap is left between the edge of a view and a subview.

You can avoid this by uncheck `Constraint to margins` while adding constraints.

[image]

Comment: yeah, That's it, Tanx a lot